# Is there a shorter way to provide an Observable onComplete handler?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm working with an Observable chain and I'm not interested in the next or error values, only when the chain has fully complete.  It feels wrong to tap into the subscribe method and supply 2 noops for next and error just so I can provide an `onComplete` callback.

For Example:

```
let isRunning = true;

Observable.from([1000, 2000, 3000])
  .concatMap(value => Observable.timer(value)
  .subscribe(
    () => {},
    () => {},
    () => isRunning = false;
  );
```

What I'd like is something that looks like this

```
let isRunning = true;

Observable.from([1000, 2000, 3000])
  .concatMap(value => Observable.timer(value)
  .onComplete(() => isRunning = false);
```

Comment: You can call subscribe() with only one function and it will work. The function itself is not unary, but it doesn't complain.

Comment: @Burimi But then it's a next handler, not a complete handler.

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot. Than you can pass undefined in the first 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest form would be use observer object.

`obs.subscribe({ complete: () => isRunning = false });`

Comment: This is one character longer than using null arguments, thus objectively not "the shortest".

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no shortcut. However, you can pass `null` instead of empty functions.

```
obs$.subscribe(null, null, () => this.isRunning = false);
```

If you want some kind of trick you could also do

```
obs$.last().subscribe(() => this.isRunning = false);
```

This would make sense if, for example, you need access to the last emitted value in the completion handler.